# Swipe Tabs - two tabs with listview + adapter

Tags: java, android

I try to implement an applicationbar with SWIPE tabs in my android project.
Lets say I've two tabs (tab1 and tab2). And I want to display different content on these tabs.
(Actually that's all what I want to do nothing more).

Tab1 includes a list and Tab2 includes "another" list plus some text.
Is it possible to use two "activities" for the two tabs? (That's what I'm doing now)

I use a custom adapter to set the lists content.

```
 final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tab1_list);
 lv.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, tab1Items));
```

But I'm not able to display the tabs content correctly. Either they aren't display at all, or they are display the same content.

Does anyone have some good ideas for me, or some little code examples, how to use a appbar with tabs and lists in it (that are using adapters)?

I'm very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example what you want "A swipe Tab":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"/>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Define the PagerAdapter :

```
package com.andy.fragments.viewpager;

import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Define the Tab FragmentActivity:

```
package com.andy.fragments.tabs;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

import com.andy.R;
import com.andy.fragments.viewpager.PagerAdapter;


public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.TabInfo>();
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    private class TabInfo {
         private String tag;
         private Class<?> clss;
         private Bundle args;
         private Fragment fragment;
         TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
             this.tag = tag;
             this.clss = clazz;
             this.args = args;
         }

    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;

        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }


        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }

    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tabs_viewpager_layout);

        this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); 
        }

        this.intialiseViewPager();
    }


    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); 
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    private void intialiseViewPager() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab2Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }


    private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", Tab1Fragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", Tab2Fragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", Tab3Fragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }


    private static void AddTab(TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {

        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }


    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {

        int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {


    }


    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a layout approach ? Create a layout in which put a tab host like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android1:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android1:layout_width="match_parent"
android1:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TabWidget
    android1:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android1:layout_width="match_parent"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TabWidget>

<FrameLayout
    android1:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android1:layout_width="match_parent"
    android1:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android1:id="@+id/tab1"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android1:id="@+id/tab2"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android1:id="@+id/tab3"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

So, in LinearLayout with id *tab1* you can add first list (and so on).